# Adding a stand alone php (with sql queries built using mysql phpgenerator) to existing Joomla application

Tags: php, sql

I am totally new to Joomla development in specific but have done good old prog days (C, Oracle, Sybase etc). So i use a Library software in Joomla and do all the installation, admin etc thing.. i want to add some SQL queries for backend and front end access. The stand alone php files i am generating for this is via a proven php generator tool called MySQL PHP generator (pro edition) from sqlmeastro. 
How can i add the php file generated to my Joomla Library application? Greatly appreciate any/every help/tips from the experts in this forum please.

regards,
parag

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) plugin to embed your php code quickly in joomla content, module, componen etc

Comment: @ParagP if this answer satisfies, please mark it as accepted by awarding it the big green tick.